# Kendo UI and jquery scrollTop not working correctly on ios and android browsers

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, scrolltop

When using the kendo ui - grid control, I found that resetting the data source does not automatically re-position the grids scroll position to the top.

This might be expected behaviour so after refreshing the datasource I added a call jquery scrollTop(0). This works on desktop browsers but not on the iPad.

```
$("#switch-data-btn").on("click", function(){ 
    grid.dataSource.data(currentData);
    grid.dataSource.transport.data = currentData;
    grid.content.scrollTop(0);
    grid.refresh();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BFAnK/6/

I decided to then go nuclear and instead of refreshing the grid data, I destroy the grid and rebuild it. When doing this I no longer need the scrollTop(0) call and all is well with the world.

```
$("#switch-data-btn").on("click", function() {
  buildGrid(currentData); 
  // buildGrid() destroys the grid, empties the dom element and recreates it.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BFAnK/11/

The above solution is not ideal but works for that limited scenario. But as soon as you introduce a scenario where you want the grid to scroll to down to a specific position using scrollTop() the iPad behavior scrolls to the position BUT prevents you from scrolling back up to see and stick earlier results (yet works on desktop browsers).

```
$("#switch-data-btn").on("click", function() {
  buildGrid(currentData);
  grid.content.scrollTop(50);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BFAnK/12/

Any ideas on how to efficiently reload data into an existing kendo gri and scroll to a desired position that works across IE9+, Chrome, Firefox and iOS and Android browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo wraps grid in scroll wrapper. You can use this code to scroll it to Top:

```
grid.wrapper.find(".km-scroll-container").css("-webkit-transform", "");
```

**UPD:**

Official answer from Kendo support:

The scrollTop method is not working because on touch screen devices the Grid uses mobile scroller.
You can reset it with the reset method. For example:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.content.data("kendoMobileScroller").reset();
```

Note that executing this code on desktop browser will produce an error.
If you want to support both scenarios you can use kendo.support.mobileOS - if it is undefined then the Grid is opened on a desktop browser where scrollTop should be used.